# How to config transparent proxy on openwrt

Tags: proxy, squid, openwrt, transparentproxy

I have a squid3 proxy server with 2 squid process running on dfferent port, as following:

- one squid running on "http_port 808"
- another running on "http_port 809 transparent" and has an iptable rule running as `iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp  --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 809`

I use proxy in 2 way:

1. set proxy ip:808 into Internet Explorer option
2. set proxy server as gateway in Windows network settings

These 2 mode works well.

Now I have a Linksys 1900AC router and have flashed openwrt 15.05. I want it to work as a transparent proxy so that every computer connected to this router could surf the Internet without setting Internet Explorer option.

After some search, I found this [Wiki link](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/uci/firewall#transparent_proxy_rule_external), but it doesn't  work.

If I set `option dest_port  809`, my chrome browser shows "access denied" or something like that. If I set `option dest_port  808`, the squid "cuts off" my website URL.  Say that I enter http://www.bing.com/images, squid just tells me that it "cannot find URL '/images'".

Has anyone succeeded on this transparent proxy stuff?